# Superposition theorem for a Wheatstone bridge

Tags: resistors, generator, short-circuit, wheatstone-bridge, superposition

I'm applying the superposition theorem to a Wheatstone bridge. I attached the picture. In this circuit there are two voltage generators: the first/top one is replaced by a wire. That's why there is a short circuit. I'm trying to get the current in the resistor 5.
How does the current flow in the circuit?
Since that short circuit is disorienting me.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the way the circuit is drawn can easily throw many people off. 
With a confusing-looking circuit or a portion of a circuit, redrawing it is usually a good way to see it from another, clearer perspective. 
If we take your circuit and rotate it, we get this:

[image]

Drawing the schematic of it slightly differently, we get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKGQAN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Next step in re-drawing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpJpj3.png)</sup>

And now the final, "magic" ;) step:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Vtn3.png)</sup>

It is now clear that R2 and R3 are connected in parallel, as well as the R1 and R4, and that those two parallel "banks" are connected in series with each other:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsukUx.png)</sup>

Now it's just a matter of adding up those three resistances in series and calculating the current from the applied voltage (voltage generator/source E) through all of them. I'm sure you know the rest.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frdesT.png)</sup>

NOTE: I have placed specific values on the voltage source and resistors, but you can ignore them.